# Rig moving after clearing all frames

Tags: animation

I've been trying to create some new moves for my creature and I created a new action for it. After clearing all the frames, some of the frames are still yellow (left-down corner frame numbers) and the foot is moving in an odd way.

Can' t understand what is this..

Comment: Here' s the .blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37660

Comment: Also, could you answer to this one: Why can' t I move the spine or torso of this creature? Is it just bad rig or I've missed something important?